# Defining the []= operator

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm writing a class Grid whose elements are Points - an (int) grid each of whose squares has a (double) point in it. I've already defined this (the height value is stored elsewhere):

```
Point &operator[](Point p) { return floor(get_x(p)) + height * floor(get_y(p)); }
```

and I want to define the assignment operator. How would one go about this? Is it defined automatically based on the `[]` operator?

So far I have

```
Point &operator[]=(Point p, Point q) { data[floor(get_y(p)) * height + floor(get_x(p))] = q; }
```

but that seems like a circular definition.

Comment: `operator[]` should certainly not return a reference to the grid! And it doesn't, in your definition, but that's going to cause the first error when the declared return type is `Grid&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not how it works, the `[]` operator should return a reference the element at that index, and that *element* (type) should support `operator=` (i.e. `Point::operator=`)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I should have seen that before. So it pretty much uses a pointer.

Comment: @jclancy whether it uses a pointer or not is an implementation detail.